# How to use AjaxSubmitButtom in yii

Tags: php, yii

Here is my code for `ajaxsubmitbutton`

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Assign',CController::createUrl('StudentsGuardian/Create',array('$guardian_id'=>$id,'$student_id'=>'js:studentid'),array('dataType'=>'html', 'complete'=>'js:alert("hurray")'))); ?>
```

But this submit button is not working. I need to call a controller`s action from this ajax button but unable to do that. Here is my controller create action

```
public function actionCreate($guardian_id, $student_id)
    {

             CVarDumper::Dump($guardian_id,100,true);
             CVarDumper::Dump($student_id,100,true);
            die();
        $model=new StudentsGuardian;

                $model->guardian_id = $guardian_id;
                $model->student_id = $student_id;
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    }
```

I have put VarDumper to see the values but this is never shown bcz Ajaxbutton when pushed just renders the view it belongs to. it do nothing.
 I am a newbie to yii so please help me and point me to the right way.
**Update:**
Here is my javascript code in which srudentId is set

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var studentid;
        $("#dropdownId").change(function(){
          studentid= $('#dropdownId :selected').val();

        });

    </script>
```

When droplist is changed then this studentid is set.

Answer (score 0):

this will never work because studentid is not set,
and it's not meant to be used this way,it will always be empty upon page load, so always is empty

and also ajaxSubmitButton send the associated form via I think GET method, you need to get your parameters from GET

Comment: actually i dont need that value at page load. When dropDownList is changed then Javascript is called then its value is set.

Comment: first "'$student_id'=>'js:studentid"' , second "actionCreate($guardian_id, $student_id)"

Answer (score 0):

Change the DataType method to POST type

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Assign',
    CController::createUrl('StudentsGuardian/Create'),
    array('type' => 'POST',
        'data' => array('guardian_id' => $id, 'student_id'=> 'js:studentid'),
        'complete' => 'js:alert("hurray")'
    )
); ?>
```

What is this 'js:studentid'?

**Controller:**

```
public function actionCreate($guardian_id, $student_id)
{
    $guardian_id = isset($_POST['guardian_id'])? $_POST['guardian_id'] : $guardian_id;
    $student_id = isset($_POST['student_id'])? $_POST['student_id'] : $student_id;

    CVarDumper::Dump($guardian_id,100,true);
    CVarDumper::Dump($student_id,100,true);
    die();
    $model=new StudentsGuardian;

    $model->guardian_id = $guardian_id;
    $model->student_id = $student_id;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

}
```